# Why is vim red highlighting closing tags in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, vim, django-templates, neovim

The image is below. Does anybody know why this is happening? I'm using neovim. Filetype is set to htmldjango.

[image]

Output from :syn list

[image]

[image]

The last lines of the output of :scriptnames

[image]

Comment: You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim).) When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Ingo. I ran the commands you suggested but not sure where to take it from there. I updated the question with the output.

Comment: It could be anything that extends the main syntax; there are often bad unforseen interactions. vim-css-color and rainbow plugins look suspect.

Comment: Thank you, Ingo. It looks like this is a known issue with the rainbow parentheses plugin: https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow/issues/105

Comment: Ah, great you've found the root cause!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Rainbow Parentheses:

https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow/issues/105

You can disable this plugin for the htmldjango filetype by setting the configuration to 0 like so in your .vimrc or init.vim

```
    let g:rainbow_conf = {
\   'guifgs': ['royalblue3', 'darkorange3', 'seagreen3', 'firebrick'],
\   'ctermfgs': ['lightblue', 'lightyellow', 'lightcyan', 'lightmagenta'],
\   'operators': '_,_',
\   'parentheses': ['start=/(/ end=/)/ fold', 'start=/\[/ end=/\]/ fold', 'start=/{/ end=/}/ fold'],
\   'separately': {
\       '*': {},
\       'tex': {
\           'parentheses': ['start=/(/ end=/)/', 'start=/\[/ end=/\]/'],
\       },
\       'lisp': {
\           'guifgs': ['royalblue3', 'darkorange3', 'seagreen3', 'firebrick', 'darkorchid3'],
\       },
\       'vim': {
\           'parentheses': ['start=/(/ end=/)/', 'start=/\[/ end=/\]/', 'start=/{/ end=/}/ fold', 'start=/(/ end=/)/ containedin=vimFuncBody', 'start=/\[/ end=/\]/ containedin=vimFuncBody', 'start=/{/ end=/}/ fold containedin=vimFuncBody'],
\       },
\       'html': {
\           'parentheses': ['start=/\v\<((area|base|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|keygen|link|menuitem|meta|param|source|track|wbr)[ >])@!\z([-_:a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\s+[-_:a-zA-Z0-9]+(\=("[^"]*"|'."'".'[^'."'".']*'."'".'|[^ '."'".'"><=`]*))?)*\>/ end=#</\z1># fold'],
\       },
\       'htmldjango': 0,
\       'css': 0,
\   }
\}
```